# Combinar Conjunto de 5 laços " for "

Tags: javascript

Estou criando uma identificação única para cada id , que funciona assim:  os 2 últimos dígitos validam os 9 anteriores com um algoritmo.

Estou criando uma função que encontra os 5 primeiros dígitos, conforme 6 últimos dados., em todas combinações possíveis!

O código funciona, mas não como deveria... 
Fiz 5 laços for , conforme abaixo:

```
function executar(v){ // função principal
        logg("Inicio da Operacao...");
         for(var x=get('x');x<10;x++){
           for(var y=get('y');y<10;y++){
             for(var z=get('z');z<10;z++){
              for(var k=get('k');k<10;k++){
                for(var w=get('w');w<10;w++){
                 var clc = ""+x+""+y+""+z+""+k+""+w+""+v;
                 if(validarID(clc)){
                  logg(clc+": é uma possibilidade válida!");
                  pause(x,y,z,k,w);
                  return true;
                 }
                 logg(clc+": não e válido.");
               }
              }
             }
            }
           }
         logg("Fim da Operacao.");
         return false;
    }

function pause(x,y,z,k,w){
   set('x',x);
   set('y',y);
   set('z',z);
   set('k',k);
   set('w',parseInt(w)+1);
}
function set(id, valor){//guarda variáveis pra continuar depois
   document.getElementById(id).value=valor;
}
function get(id){//recupera valores apos pause
   return parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value);
}
function logg(msg){
      var obj = document.getElementById('log');
          obj.value = obj.value + "\n";
          obj.value = obj.value +  ">> " +msg;
          setTimeout(function(){
                obj.scrollTop = obj.scrollHeight;
            }, 500);
}

function validarID(id) { 
    // 
}
```

#### Saída:

> ```
> // - - - - Exemplo de saída - - - //
> // - - - - Dado: (833703): - - - - //
> // - - - - Tinha colocado hora min seg etc mas não e importante - - - //
>
>
> 10s075ms>> Inicio da Operacao...
> 10s076ms>> 00001833703: failed.
> 10s076ms>> 00002833703: failed.
> 10s076ms>> 00003833703: failed.
> 10s076ms>> 00004833703: failed.
> 10s076ms>> 00005833703: failed.
> 10s076ms>> 00006833703: failed.
> 10s077ms>> 00007833703: failed.
> 10s077ms>> 00008833703: failed.
> 10s077ms>> 00009833703: failed.
> 10s077ms>> 00011833703: failed.
> 10s077ms>> 00012833703: failed.
> 10s077ms>> 00013833703: failed.
> 10s077ms>> 00014833703: failed.
> 10s078ms>> 00015833703: failed.
> 10s078ms>> 00016833703: failed.
> 10s078ms>> 00017833703: failed.
> 10s078ms>> 00018833703: failed.
> 10s078ms>> 00019833703: failed.
> 10s078ms>> 00021833703: failed.
> 10s079ms>> 00022833703: failed.
> 10s079ms>> 00023833703: failed.
> 10s079ms>> 00024833703: failed.
> 10s079ms>> 00025833703: failed.
> 10s079ms>> 00026833703: failed.
> 10s079ms>> 00027833703: failed.
> 10s079ms>> 00028833703: failed.
> 10s079ms>> 00029833703: failed.
> 10s079ms>> 00031833703: failed.
> 10s080ms>> 00032833703: failed.
> 10s080ms>> 00033833703: failed.
> 10s080ms>> 00034833703: failed.
> 10s080ms>> 00035833703: failed.
> 10s080ms>> 00036833703: is correct!
> 11s622ms>> Inicio da Operacao...
> 11s622ms>> 00037833703: failed.
> 11s623ms>> 00038833703: failed.
> 11s623ms>> 00039833703: failed.
> 11s624ms>> 00047833703: failed.
> 11s624ms>> 00048833703: failed.
> 11s624ms>> 00049833703: failed.
> 11s624ms>> 00057833703: failed.
> 11s625ms>> 00058833703: failed.
> 11s625ms>> 00059833703: failed.
> 11s625ms>> 00067833703: failed.
> 11s625ms>> 00068833703: failed.
> 11s625ms>> 00069833703: failed.
> 11s626ms>> 00077833703: failed.
> 11s626ms>> 00078833703: failed.
> 11s626ms>> 00079833703: failed.
> 11s626ms>> 00087833703: failed.
> 11s627ms>> 00088833703: failed.
> 11s627ms>> 00089833703: failed.
> 11s627ms>> 00097833703: failed.
> 11s627ms>> 00098833703: failed.
> 11s627ms>> 00099833703: failed.
> 11s628ms>> 00137833703: failed.
> 11s628ms>> 00138833703: failed.
> 11s628ms>> 00139833703: failed.
> 11s628ms>> 00147833703: failed.
> 11s629ms>> 00148833703: failed.
> 11s629ms>> 00149833703: failed.
> 11s629ms>> 00157833703: failed.
> 11s629ms>> 00158833703: failed.
> 11s630ms>> 00159833703: failed.
> 11s630ms>> 00167833703: failed.
> 11s630ms>> 00168833703: failed.
> 11s630ms>> 00169833703: failed.
> 11s631ms>> 00177833703: failed.
> 11s631ms>> 00178833703: failed.
> 11s632ms>> 00179833703: failed.
> 11s632ms>> 00187833703: failed.
> 11s632ms>> 00188833703: failed.
> 11s632ms>> 00189833703: failed.
> 11s633ms>> 00197833703: failed.
> 11s633ms>> 00198833703: failed.
> 11s633ms>> 00199833703: failed.
> 11s633ms>> 00237833703: failed.
> 11s634ms>> 00238833703: failed.
> 11s634ms>> 00239833703: failed.
> 11s634ms>> 00247833703: failed.
> 11s634ms>> 00248833703: failed.
> 11s635ms>> 00249833703: failed.
> 11s635ms>> 00257833703: failed.
> 11s636ms>> 00258833703: failed.
> 11s636ms>> 00259833703: failed.
> 11s636ms>> 00267833703: failed.
> 11s637ms>> 00268833703: failed.
> 11s637ms>> 00269833703: failed.
> 11s637ms>> 00277833703: failed.
> 11s637ms>> 00278833703: failed.
> 11s638ms>> 00279833703: failed.
> 11s638ms>> 00287833703: failed.
> 11s638ms>> 00288833703: failed.
> 11s638ms>> 00289833703: failed.
> 11s639ms>> 00297833703: failed.
> 11s639ms>> 00298833703: failed.
> 11s639ms>> 00299833703: failed.
> 11s639ms>> 00337833703: failed.
> 11s640ms>> 00338833703: failed.
> 11s640ms>> 00339833703: failed.
> 11s640ms>> 00347833703: failed.
> 11s641ms>> 00348833703: failed.
> 11s641ms>> 00349833703: failed.
> 11s641ms>> 00357833703: failed.
> 11s642ms>> 00358833703: failed.
> 11s642ms>> 00359833703: failed.
> 11s642ms>> 00367833703: failed.
> 11s642ms>> 00368833703: failed.
> 11s643ms>> 00369833703: failed.
> 11s643ms>> 00377833703: failed.
> 11s643ms>> 00378833703: failed.
> 11s644ms>> 00379833703: failed.
> 11s644ms>> 00387833703: failed.
> 11s644ms>> 00388833703: failed.
> 11s644ms>> 00389833703: is correct!
> 12s544ms>> Inicio da Operacao...
> 12s550ms>> Fim da Operacao.
> ```

Updated: Ajustando a tipagem de valores (str / int) e omitindo função de pausar funcionou. Queria com função de pausar e retomar, mas o importante que o que eu queria funcionou.

Comment: Ué, e como ele deveria funcionar? Ele não está gerando as combinações todas? Ou a validação não funciona?

Comment: Ele esta gerando menos de 10 combinações e depois caindo no "fim da operação" , mas como testes estou fazendo na unha as possibilidades , e ha muito mais possibilidades.

Comment: Você sabe que algoritmos para fins como este não se baseiam apenas num conjunto de `ifs, elses ou loops` pois não ? Precisas é de uma boa equação e alguma lógica para fazer isso funcionar. Fora isso, existem já meios próprios para fazer o que pretendes.

Comment: Precisa mesmo de 5 loops? Não consegui ver razão que impeça de usar um único, com um número de vários dígitos, em vez de vários de um dígito (lembrando que você pode trabalhar individualmente com os dígitos dentro do loop, de qualquer forma).

Comment: Usar nested for loop com 2 níveis já é meio ineficiente, imagina com 5. Eu acho que ninguém usa mais de 2 níveis assim. Confunde muito. DEVE haver uma maneira inteligente e eficiente de fazer isso. Que tal usar variáveis e tentar usar só um loop? Pensa num algorítimo ai antes de ir pro código.

Comment: Ainda vou continuar mexendo no código pra ver se consigo deixar com função de pausar. Isso e importante pra não travar seu JavaScript no seu navegador, afinal são 10^5 = 100.000 possibilidades. No exemplo acima de entrada deu 1653 possibilidades validas.

Comment: Essa quantidade de loops não parece ser uma boa solução, imagina um cenário onde você precisar testar uma quantidade gigantesca, o tempo de espera provavelmente irá acocar o navegador!

Comment: Por mais incrível que pareça, ainda não consigo entender o propósito desse código - comparar e encontrar, e depois ? - e assim fica difícil tentar fazer o que for que seja, mas para já digo que você provavelmente está construindo mal a lógica, e você melhor do que ninguém sabe ao certo o que o código deve fazer. Se possível formule melhor o problema ou faça um resumo claro dele.